# Bootstrap dropdown menu is not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a small project using Bootstrap, and I've come across a weird problem.

Basically, I have this menu with two items, where the first loads another page inside a div, and the second triggers a dropdown menu.

The problem is that if I click on the first item right after I run the file on browser, the dropdown will stop working until I click the first item again.

If I click the second item first, the dropdown will also stop working until I click the first item.

Here's the code:

```js
$('#usuarios').click(function() {
  $('#main').load('cns_usuarios.html');
});

$('#canal').click(function() {
  $('#main').load('canal.html');
});

$('#campos').click(function() {
  $('#main').load('cns_campos.html');
});
```

```html
<link href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<ul class='breadcrumb menu'>
  <li id='usuarios'><a href='#'>Listar Usuários</a>
  </li>

  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
      Configurações
      <span class = 'caret'></span>
    </a>

    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li id='canal'><a href='#'>Canal</a>
      </li>
      <li id='campos'><a href='#'>Campos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a href='../index.html'>Sair</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id='main' class='main'>
</div>
```

The code contains some stuff in portuguese, but it's pretty much irrelevant so just ignore it.

Also, I've added a few things of my own, but only on the css side. If anyone thinks it might be causing my problem I'll show that part of the code too.

Comment: Load your js in each page or make a common layout and import in each page

Comment: you can easily try by paste your js code in console where your drop-down menu is not working

Comment: put your jquery and bootstrap javascript in bottom part of body
and there is no `</main>` in `<div id = 'main' class = 'main'></main>` instead `</div>`

Comment: seems working fine... "The problem is that if I click on the first item right after I run the file on browser, the dropdown will stop working until I click the first item again.

If I click the second item first, the dropdown will also stop working until I click the first item."

Comment: Can you see any error in inspect / firebug console?

Comment: Have you tried your code in Chrome, using the console to see the errors. I have previously had experiences with Bootstrap conflicting with other CSS/Jquery etc..

Comment: I checked on console and there are no errors.

Comment: Putting the js code on the bottom part of the body doesn't work either, and my code doesn't work on chrome because I'm loading by files instead of http, so the load function doesn't even work on chrome yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#usuarios', function() {
        $('#main').load('cns_usuarios.html');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#canal', function() {
        $('#main').load('canal.html');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#campos', function() {
        $('#main').load('cns_campos.html');
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Tried that, still got the same problem.

Comment: check the `#main` div append any html text `$('#main').html('This is the test.');`

Comment: When I append text instead of using the load function the menu works absolutely fine.